# AWSSDK - DynamoDB delete items by term and add automatic create date attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I want to know if there is option to add in creation table automatic attribute or something like this that will save the create date of each "row" in table . I search on amazon documentation and didn't found something like this , I am new with dynamoDB ,and I do not have a lot of knowledge.. 
So , It's possible ?

Another issue - I want delete items (use on DeleteItemRequest) by filter on the date attribute - it's possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add an attribute on each item automatically. What we do is for each element we want to have this we add a String called createdTime and populate it with a UTC milliseconds string.

When you delete you must have a full primary key (hash / hash+range) of the item you wish to delete. So in order to do that you either Query or Scan with a filter, to get the items you want to delete, and then run a delete item request (or batch) on them to remove them.